# Write the hexadecimal value of a string to external file with C

Tags: c, hex

I need to write the hexadecimal value of each char in A string to an external file , each char on A different line.

For example if I have this string

> "am+ij"

The external file should look like that:

```
061
06D
02B
069
06A
```

How can I do something like that?
(sorry if the question is not well written, i couldn't think of any other way to explain what i need to do)

Comment: Please show as much of the code as you know how to do. Otherwise we don't know what specific part you need help with. Do you know how to get a file name? How to open a file? Declare a string? Iterate characters in a string? Write formatted output? etc.

Comment: Either read the entire line `"am+ij"` into an array with `fgets()` and loop over the characters in the array writing each out using `fprintf (filePtr, "%03x\n", c);` (stopping when you reach `'\n'`) or read a character at a time with e.g. `getchar()` and do it that way.

Comment: sadly i don't have a code to show, but i just need to know how to write the hexa value of the chars to the file, all the other parts I do know how to do.

Comment: The characters will be type `unsigned char` cast to `int` (that's how they are handled). So, e.g. `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) fprintf (filePtr, "%03x\n", c);` (of course you want to open the file before that, e.g. `FILE *filePtr = fopen (name_of_file, "w");` and close it when you are done. For testing, you can just set `FILE *filePtr = stdout;'` and write the output to your terminal. When you are happy, then open the actual output file to write the output to the file.

Answer (score 2):

I have outlined the process in the comments. In C characters are treated as `unsigned char` cast to `int` by all character functions like `getchar()`, etc. So after reading a character, all you need to do is write it out in hex format. For any value, whether you look at it as decimal, octal or hex, the number does NOT change, it is just how you choose to represent it. So when you read a character `'a'` it has the [ASCII Value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `97` decimal or `61` hex, and `'m'` has the ASCII value of `109` decimal or `6d` hex.

You just want to read each character (which actually reads its ASCII value) and then output it in hexadecimal format. You do that with `printf()/fprintf()`. So in this case, you simply want to declare an `int` and then read each character assigning it to your variable and then write the variable out to your file in hex format (formatted zero-padded with a *field-width* of `3`). You do that with the conversion specifier `"%03x"` for output like `06d`, or use `"%03X"` if you want the hex characters in upper-case, e.g. `06D`.

A minimal short example that reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout` could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    
    int c;
    
    fputs ("enter string: ", stdout);
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        printf ("%03x\n", c);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readwrite_char2hex
enter string: am+ij
061
06d
02b
069
06a
```

This leaves the file opening and use of `fscanf()` to you as well a choosing the case to output hex digits in. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.